# Leaflet and Tangram conctenated into a single script file

Tags: gruntjs, leaflet

I am trying to concat leaflet and tangram source codes into a single script file using grunt to include it in an api which I am trying to make based on both leaflet and tangram. If I include the leaflet and tangram js files using different script tags in the html, the code works perfectly. But If i concat them using grunt and use a single script file I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

The example code which I tried to run is as follows:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([12.96,77.58],14);
var layer = Tangram.leafletLayer({
scene: '../scene/scene.yaml',
      });
layer.addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([12.96,77.58]).addTo(map);
```

Any kind of help is very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The webworkers that tangram uses require tangram to be included on the page as 'tangram.min.js' or 'tangram.debug.js'

It looks like that will be fixed at some point soon, but for now you will have to include it seperately.